# How to move image down each time button is pressed Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a tkinter application where every time you press a <kbd>button</kbd> an image moves down a certain number of pixels. For example, the first time it is placed at `y=30` and then the next time the button is pressed it is placed at `y=60` etc. Is there any way to do this? I do not want to use the `pack()` method as I need to place the image in a specific location on the screen using x and y coordinates.

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')

def display():
        box_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='apple.png')
        panel2 = tk.Label(root, image=box_image, bg='#f7f6f6')
        panel2.image = box_image
        panel2.place(x=30, y=30 + 30) #i was thinking about doing something like adding 30 each time but this didn't work


button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=display)
button.place(x=0, y=0)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following :

```
import calendar
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')


x = 30
y = 30
box_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'apple.png')

def display():
    global x , y
    panel2 = tk.Label(root, image=box_image, bg='#f7f6f6')
    panel2.place(x=x+30, y=y+30) 
    x = x+30
    y = y+30


button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=display)
button.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not wish for the 1 image to be moved, I wish for multiple image to appear on the page e.g. if you click the button 3 times, 3 images will be placed on the page underneath each other.

Comment: do you mean that you want to create the same image in different position (according to the pixels that you want ) ?

Comment: @Minbutt I edit my answer . Take a look .